# How to send API post request for download pdf using url in react?

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I have user data in a table and wanted to make a post request to a specific url to download in PDF format. Basically, it should return me an ID and with that, I can send get request which generates a pdf document. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${API_PATH}pdf/generate`,
      data: service
    })
    .then((res) => console.log("response",res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(["APIGet error:", err]));
  };
```

**service** is a data with array of objects. For now response is 400 bad request not sure where I am doing wrong at. Please help!

Comment: Why is a java tag on this post?

Comment: cause api was built by java , i  was just wondering maybe there is something to do with be